# How to skip login in cakephp 2.6.7?

Tags: cakephp

I have an old cakephp application which requires login. I was working with the tables in phpmyadmin and I accidentally deleted the user login/password entry from the table. Now I am not able to login in the cakephp application. I tried to create a login entry in the table but I am not sure how to insert a password in it. it is not working with plain text password. I guess, app is looking for encrypted password which I don't know how to add to the table.

Either I need to disable the login from the cakephp application code and direct the user straight to the main page of the app
Or I need to encrypt the password correctly and insert it in the table.

Please help!  I am not sure how to achieve either of these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Users Controller and add the actions you need to create and save a new user:

```
$this->Auth->allow('display','save');
```

so, you'll be able to anter to that controller actions without any login.

Comment: Sir, is there any way  I can generate a password and insert it the table manually?

Comment: Are the passwords encrypted in your users database?
- Obviously i'm thinking you have total acces to your database.

Comment: yes.  I tried to put a sh1, md5 hash. but it didn't work.